Performance issue with BigQuery to_dataframe() on Vertex AI
Problem:
I'm facing a significant performance issue when executing a BigQuery query in a Vertex AI pipeline. Here's the example code:
query = "SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table`"  # returns 5,000,000 rows
query_job = client.query(query)
df = query_job.result().to_dataframe()

The instruction df = query_job.result().to_dataframe() takes around 50 minutes to execute on Vertex AI, whereas it only takes less than 5 minutes on my local machine.
.set_cpu_limit("60")
.set_memory_limit("128G")

I'm using the to_dataframe() method to load the data into a Pandas DataFrame, it returns around 5 millions rows.
Questions:

Why is this operation much slower on Vertex AI compared to a local machine?
What adjustments can I make to the Vertex configuration or the code to improve the performance of this operation?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Load data from Google BigQuery you can also usepandas_gbq.read_gbq
as an alternative to improve the performance & refer to this Doc once .
You can  also try to run your query faster on Bigquery using query optimization

not using select*  , try to specify the column & row  name ,

to load whole data from dataset it can delay . use can use limit.


You can check this doc Optimize query computation  and Convert Bigquery results to Pandas Data Frame

Thank you for your feedback! But I am talking the opposite, from Big Query to python dataframe not the opposite.

HI , I have modified my answer , and you can use Query  Optimization  techniques and  If you want to get detailed investigation on the issue you can open bug request  as per your requirements on the public issue tracker  describing your issue and Eng team will look on the issue for future implementation .

You can find some suggestions here: Convert Bigquery results to Pandas Data Frame . Let us know if any of it works for you.


Can you try installing all the extras?

pip install 'google-cloud-bigquery[all]'


Can you create the Notebook instance in same location/region as your BigQuery database?

